# How to decide which table should have a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql

In my scenario we have 3 tables that have a 1:M relationship. The tables are

```
Device
Event
Function
```

Each Device can have 1 or many Functions, and 1 or many Events. Hence, I have created the tables as such:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Function` (
  `functionId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `functionType` TEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`functionId`))

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Event` (
  `eventId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `eventType` TEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`eventId`))

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Device` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `function_Id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `event_Id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_Device_Function_idx` (`function_Id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Device_Event1_idx` (`event_Id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Device_Function`
    FOREIGN KEY (`function_Id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Function` (`functionId`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Device_Event1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`event_Id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Event` (`eventId`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION))
```

For instance, if we have 3 devices, we then insert all 3 into the devices into the Devices table, but, if there are no events yet, then what do we use for the event_Id field? Default value?

The one consideration I thought of was switching the event table around such that it contained the foreign key to the device - but wouldn't that be events having 1 or more devices?

The majority queries done one this database will be all events for all devices in a given time period (there will be a date column in the event table omitted). Hence, if the device contains the key to the event, how would you get all the events for all the devices?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a possibility that 2 devices can have same function or same event ?

Comment: Events are per device. So a single event corresponds to a single device. Devices can have the same function - e.g. keyboard device will have a button function, every keyboard device will have that function, but the function will relate back to the device for when the event occurs on that keyboard device.